# PHP imap not connecting

Tags: php

I am using the PHP function `imap_open` with this code:

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect: ' . imap_last_error());

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

if($emails) {
    echo 'emails!';
} else {
    echo 'no emails';
}
```

i have tried with emails in the inbox and with none but nothing displays on the screen

i think its something to do with an add on not being installed on the server

it is running Centos 6 and Centos Web Panel software

Comment: Are there any errors? Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: reporting on using error_reporting(-1); but not errors at all. its not getting past the $inbox... line i have put echo 'test'; just below this line and nothing shows, but above that line it shows

Comment: I am not 100% sure but you are probably missing _php-imap_ library. Check with `phpinfo()` or `php -m` if you have access to linux terminal.